# Polymorphism and Class Abstraction Example in C++

Tags: c++, delegates, polymorphism, abstract-class

Trying to get my head round using polymorphism in C++. Below are two base abstract classes, `Duck` and `FlyingBehavior`, and a series of inherited classes (this is based on the first chapter from *Head First Design Patterns*).

```
// Define an abstract fly behaviour class
class FlyBehavior {
public:
    virtual void fly() { cout << "No Flying Set!" << endl; }
};

class FlySwoop : public FlyBehavior {
public:
    void fly() { cout << "Swoop Flying!" << endl; }
};

class CantFly : public FlyBehavior {
public:
    void fly() { cout << "Can't Fly!" << endl; }
};

// Define an abstract Duck class
class Duck {
    CantFly nf;
    FlyBehavior *flyBehavior;
public:     
    Duck() { flyBehavior = &nf; }
    void goFly() { flyBehavior->fly(); }
    void setFlyBehavior(FlyBehavior *fb) { flyBehavior = fb; }
};

// Define a new Mallard Duck class
class MallardDuck : public Duck {
    FlySwoop fb;
public:
    MallardDuck(){ setFlyBehavior(&fb); }
};

// Define a new Rubber Duck class
class RubberDuck : public Duck {
    CantFly fb;
public:
    RubberDuck(){ setFlyBehavior(&fb); }
};

// Define a new Toilet Duck Class
class ToiletDuck : public Duck {};

int main(void) {

    Duck *p;
    MallardDuck mallardDuck;
    RubberDuck rubberDuck;
    ToiletDuck toiletDuck;
    p = &mallardDuck;
    p->goFly();
    p = &rubberDuck;
    p->goFly();
    p = &toiletDuck;
    p->goFly();

}
```

Using the above code I get the following output

```
Swoop Flying!
Can't Fly!
Can't Fly!
```

when I was expecting

```
Swoop Flying!
Can't Fly!
No Flying Set!
```

Am I approaching this example the right way (use to doing it in Java)? Can't help but feel that I'm missing something fundamental. I'm trying to understand how you pull out a behaviour from a class, put it into another class, and then use polymorphism to delegate to the right behavior. Is there a better way to approach the above?

Hmmm, perhaps this where you use multiple inheritance instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you change

```
class Duck {
    CantFly nf;
    FlyBehavior *flyBehavior;
public:     
    Duck() { flyBehavior = &nf; }
    void goFly() { flyBehavior->fly(); }
    void setFlyBehavior(FlyBehavior *fb) { flyBehavior = fb; }
};
```

to

```
class Duck {
    FlyBehavior nf;
    FlyBehavior *flyBehavior;
public:     
    Duck() { flyBehavior = &nf; }
    void goFly() { flyBehavior->fly(); }
    void setFlyBehavior(FlyBehavior *fb) { flyBehavior = fb; }
};
```

your code will produce desired output.

In the current version of the code `ToiletDuck` compiler-generated default constructor calls a default constructor of the `Duck` class which sets `nf` to point to an instance of the`CantFly` class. Of course, it prints `Can't fly`.

Comment: D'oh, yes of course! On a more general note, is this sort of use of polymorphism and delegation typical in C++? I'm use to Java, so I might be trying to do it in a manner which is not really suitable for C++. Would really appreciate any brief thoughts.

Comment: @JamesB I would say that it is fine because there are lot of ways to do the same thing in C++ and its a matter of choice which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code has **no abstract base** classes. An abstract base class is one that has pure `virtual` member functions (such as `virtual fly() const=0`). `FlyBehavior` is a polymorphic class, but not abstract, since its virtual function is not pure virtual. `Duck` is not even a polymorphic class (has no virtual member methods).

Second, any polymorphic classes should have a `virtual` destructor, so that any object of derived type can be deleted from a pointer to the polymorphic base.

Next, the derived ducks have more data members than actually used. `MallardDuck`, for example, has a `CantFly`, a `FlySwoop` and a `FlyBehaviour*`. This can be avoided by allocating the actual `FlyBehaviour` on the heap and managing it through a smart pointer. (This may not be an issue with this simple example, but as soon as those objects get large it will become a problem.)

Finally, the member function `setFlyBehavior()` is exposed to the public, allowing the user to change the `FlyBehavior` -- do you really want that?

A possible design is as follows

```
struct FlyBehavior    // polymorphic class
{
  virtual void fly() const { cout << "No Flying Set!" << endl; }
  virtual~FlyBehavior() {}
};

struct FlySwoop : FlyBehavior
{
  void fly() const { cout << "Swoop Flying!" << endl; }
};

struct CantFly : FlyBehavior
{
  void fly() const { cout << "Can't Fly!" << endl; }
};

class Duck        // non-polymorphic, but using polymorphism through member
{
  std::unique_ptr<FlyBehavior> flyBehavior; // calls FlyBehavior::~FlyBehavior at destruction
protected:
  explicit Duck(FlyBehavior*f) : flyBehavior(f) { assert(f); }
public:     
  Duck() : flyBehavior(new FlyBehavior) {}  // note: not CantFly as in your code
  Duck(Duck&&) = default;                   // allow move (but no copy)
  Duck&operator=(Duck&&) = default;
  void goFly() const { flyBehavior->fly(); }
};

struct MallardDuck : Duck
{
  MallardDuck() : Duck(new FlySwoop) {}
};

struct RubberDuck : Duck
{
  RubberDuck() : Duck(new CantFly) {}
};
```

Often it is preferrable for `FlyBehavior` to be abstract. In this case, `Duck` can be implemented with only a `protected` constructor (apart from move & copy):

```
struct FlyBehavior    // polymorphic class
{
  virtual void fly() const=0 ;   // pure virtual
  virtual~FlyBehavior() {}
};

class Duck        // non-polymorphic, but using polymorphism through member
{
  std::unique_ptr<FlyBehavior> flyBehavior; // calls FlyBehavior::~FlyBehavior at destruction
protected:
  explicit Duck(FlyBehavior*f) : flyBehavior(f) { assert(f); }
public:
  Duck() = delete;                          // no default constructor
  Duck(Duck&&) = default;                   // allow move (but no copy)
  Duck&operator=(Duck&&) = default;
  void goFly() const { flyBehavior->fly(); }
};
```

and the remaining code as above. The difference is that you cannot create a `Duck` object, but only one of the derived Duck types. Which of these two designs is most suitable depends on the application.

Comment: Great, thanks Walter. I've learnt a lot following through your example, and got my first introduction to unique pointers.